# How to extract json Objects from String Builder?

Tags: java, json

I have string builder of the form:

```
[{"abc" : ["something1", "something2"]}, {"def" : ["something3", "something4"]}]
```

How do I convert it so that I can perform get on the keys? For e.g.: object.get("abc") and i get the list back.

I looked around for solutions:

I tried doing:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

I get the following exception:

```
exception org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I then tried taking a sub-string of the Json, like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString().substring(1, sb.toString().length()-1));
```

which gives back:

```
jsonObjwct {"Z-DwY2Ul":["Worried Blues","Worried Blues"]}
```

I get only the first object, i need all of them.

What modifications i can do to get the list back for a specific key?

Comment: As you can see the string starts with an `[` which means it is a `JsonArray` not an `JsonObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`'s, so first convert it into `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

And then you can iterate by using `for` loop

```
 for (int i = 0, size = array.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject obj = array.optJSONObject(i);   //{"abc" : ["something1", "something2"]}
   }
```

Comment: On doing `array.optJSONObject(i);` , I get: `{"Z-DwY2Ul":["Worried Blues","Worried Blues"]}`. How to get the list from this? Is there a way to store this to a Map? I tried various ways such as:  `obj.optString(key1)`. Is there a way I could store this to a Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: There is no straight method, you have to write a loop @Mahima